# Importing all modules in scope

Tags: javascript, npm

In NPM, is it possible to import all the modules in a scope?

say I have a scope in my artifact

```
@myorg/m1
@myorg/m2
@myorg/m3
....
@myorg/mn
```

My current app depends on all the packages in @myorg. Is there an option or way to say in my package.json that I want to import all of them together?

Having an index.js file in @myorg will work? Before I walk down that path, wanted to check around. 
Thanks

Comment: use npm install. This commend install all the libarary files where located in package.json file. But you can manullay add all lib names in package.json

Comment: I am trying to figure out if that can be avoided. Specifying all the libraries under that namespace separately.